# Delete with LEFT OUTER JOIN in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to remove all rows from one table that don't have the corresponding key in a second table.  So for example in my `devices` table I have `id` values of 1 and 2.  In my `registrations` table I have `deviceid` of 1.

Because 2 doesn't exist in the registration table, I want to remove that row from the devices table, but leave id 1.

In Microsoft SQL I'd write something like this:

```sql
DELETE d
FROM devices d
LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations r on d.id = r.deviceid
WHERE r.deviceid IS NULL
```

What's the equivalent in PostgreSQL?  I tried the below, but it deleted *all* rows from devices:

```sql
DELETE FROM devices
USING devices AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations AS r ON d."id" = r.deviceid
WHERE r.deviceid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
delete from devices d
where not exists (select * 
                  from registrations r
                  where d.id = r.deviceid);
```

Comment: Thanks.  In 8 minutes when StackOverflow decides I've had time to read the answer I'll mark it as correct.